# How do I convert html page to SharePoint 2013 master page?

Tags: branding

There is functionality provided in SP2013 for converting html page to SharePoint master page. I have tried this functionality but each time it convert nothing. Is there any specific method that I need to follow? Or is there any specif layouts of html page need to be converted into SP 2013 master page?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822370.aspx) for converting a HTML file to a MasterPage